# CQRS asynchronously command bus vs synchronously

Tags: cqrs

I'm considering to use CQRS as architecture for a system. It's a web application. But I don't like the use of a asynchronous command bus because it makes the feedback to the user a pain. I.e you can't tell the user if the command succeeded or failed. When using a synchronously command bus you can. So what is the real benefit of a asynchronous bus?

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in reading the [Reactive Manifesto](http://www.reactivemanifesto.org/), which is strongly related to your question and particularly gives reasons for asynchronous processing.  This gives some good reasons for employing an asynchronous design from the beginning, even if it is a burden for the programmer sometimes.

On the other hand, for small projects that will never need to scale-out, it is totally find to use synchronous command processing, particularly when the team is unfamiliar with asynch programming.

Comment: Thanks Alexander.If asynchronous is that good why are there no guides/practices out there telling you how to deal with the dilemma of notifying the user triggering a command? The only solution I have seen is: Always display a "success message" to the user and send an email if the command failed.

Comment: I can recommend this video: http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Command-Query-Responsibility-Segregation